# convert enum as singleton to JSON using gson

Tags: java, enums, singleton, android, gson

I have singleton implementation of enum as below :

```
public enum DeviceDetail{

    INSTANCE;  
    private  Context context = null;
    private  int handlercheck = 0;
    private  String network = "";
    private  String deviceInfo = "NoData";
    private  String androidVersion = "";
    private  String appVersion = "";
    private  String appName = "";
    private  String deviceID;
    private  String deviceinfo;

    public void initilize(){
           // deviceInfo = getDeviceInfo();
            networktype = getNetworktype(context);
            deviceID = getDeviceID(context);
            //androidVersion = getAndroidVersion();
            appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
            appName = getAppName(context);
    }    
    DeviceDetail(){
        deviceInfo = getDeviceInfo();
        androidVersion = getAndroidVersion();
        initilize();

    }

    public static DeviceDetail getInstance() {
        return DeviceDetail.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

I want to convert this DeviceDetail to JSON using GSON, for that I have written

```
public static String convertObjectToJsonString(DeviceDetail deviceData)    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(deviceData);
    }
```

I am calling this method as

```
convertObjectToJsonString(DeviceDetail.INSTANCE)
```

but it only returns me the string "INSTANCE" not key value pairs as it does for objects. Suggest the changes need to be made so that I get string with all fields in enum in key value JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up in using a not so elegant workaround as below :

```
public static String convertObjectToJsonString(DeviceDetail deviceData) {
        // Gson gson = new Gson();
        // GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("androidVersion", deviceData.getAndroidVersion());
        jsonObject.addProperty("appName", deviceData.getAppName());
        jsonObject.addProperty("appVersion", deviceData.getAppVersion());
        jsonObject.addProperty("networkType", deviceData.getNetworktype());
        jsonObject.addProperty("deviceInfo", deviceData.getDeviceInfo());
        jsonObject.addProperty("deviceID", deviceData.getDeviceID());
        jsonObject.addProperty("city", deviceData.getCity());
        jsonObject.addProperty("country", deviceData.getCountry());
        //jsonObject.addProperty("appName",deviceData.getAppName());

        return jsonObject.toString();
    }
```